# Understanding looping structure in powershell

Tags: powershell

Please guide me how can we print alphabets from b to z
in for loop.
I want something like below:

```
for x in {b..z} {
testdata.$x }
```

I have tried the below but bit confusing I simply want to print a..z with my testdata, where should I put my testdata

```
$alphabet = @()  

for ([byte]$c = [char]'b'; $c -le [char]'d'; $c++)  
{  
    $alphabet += [char]$c  
}  

[String]::Join(", ", $alphabet)
```

Tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for ([byte]$c = [char]'b'; $c -le [char]'z'; $c++)  
{  
    "testdata.$([char]$c)"  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[char]` type accelerator converts an integer value to its ASCII character equivalent (technically it's actually the ANSI character equivalent, but let's ignore that for now, since it's irrelevant for the matter at hand).

If you take a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you'll see that uppercase letters A-Z range from 65 to 90 and lowercase letters a-z from 97 to 122. For building a list of the characters "b" through "z" use the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) to get a list of the integer values 98 through 122 and cast those to `[char]`.

```
$alphabet = 98..122 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code, 141 characters.

Autosvet's code, 52 characters.

Ansgar Wiecher's code, 49 characters

Writing the alphabet and casting it to an array of characters is shorter and clearer:

```
$alphabet = [char[]]'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

e.g

```
$alphabet | foreach-object {

    "testing-$_"

}
```

Comment: If you want to optimize by character count: `$a=98..122|%{[char]$_}`, 22 characters. ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't want to golf it as far as possible, but I think it's ridiculous and bizarre that people want 'the (English) alphabet' and instead of writing a simple, clear, string literal of 26 characters and enumerating it, people would rather write three or four times that much code, with a lot more mechanics - loops, loop variables, triple lots of casting, magic integers, multiple lines of code. Yes `98..122` is short but it's less clear that they are "ASCII characters from 'b' to 'z'" and not at all clear that 98 is intentionally starting at 'b' and not a mistake for 'a'

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers but if I did want to: `[char[]]$a=98..122` is 18 characters ;)

Comment: Oooh, nice one. Didn't think of that. ^_^

Comment: BTW, I don't disagree on the "clearer" part, although the alphabet string *is* prone to typos.